# How to manipulate strings in order to pick out specific letters within them

Tags: python-3.x, function

I've been doing practice problems online and feel I'm going about solving this problem inefficiently. The goal is to print True if the first letter of each word in a string are the same, otherwise print False.

I've tried "".join() but came out with a list of true and false unless I use the break function.

```
def animal_crackers(text):
for w in (text):
    words = text.split()
    letters = [word[0] for word in words]
    balls = "".join(letters)
    if balls[0] == balls[1]:
        print (True)
        break
    else:
        print (False)
        break
```

animal_crackers('Load Lucky') --> True

animal_crackers('Benny Mike') --> False

Answer (score 1):

This might help:

```
def is_alliteration(ww):
    return len(set([w[0].lower() for w in ww.split()])) == 1


w1 = "Blubber brewer brine"
w2 = "cat mat mot"

is_alliteration(w1) # True
is_alliteration(w2) # False
```

Comment: that second line really condenses things, I feel like I can do the same thing but my code would run a half a dozen lines at least.

Comment: Number of lines of code isn't much of an important criterion. But avoiding extra complication/unnecessary work is usually good; for instance you don't need to `"".join()` the letters - in your function, just check `len(set(letters))` and you'll know the answer (and use `.lower()` if you don't want case-sensitive results).